# How to sort column and row names in pandas crosstab?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have this pandas crosstab:

[image]

I would like to reorder the column names in such a way, that it goes like [ar, cs, de, en, es, fr, hi, it, ja, ko, pl, pt, ru, tr, zh, be, gl, la, nn, sa, ur, ...] -> eg., those elemets with high numbers are at the diagonal. I tried multiindexing, rearranging those values that go into the pandas dataframe, but cannot figure it out.

I use the pd.crosstab like

```
orig = ['ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'ar', ...]
pred = ['ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'tr', ...]
self.df_confusion = pd.crosstab(orig , pred )
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) on both axes:

```
order = ['ar', 'cs', 'de', 'en', 'es', 'fr', 'hi', 'it',
         'ja', 'ko', 'pl', 'pt', 'ru', 'tr', 'zh', 'be',
         'gl', 'la', 'nn', 'sa', 'ur']

df_confusion = df_confusion.reindex(index=order, columns=order)
```

If you want to add potentially missing values:

```
df_confusion = df_confusion.reindex(index=order, columns=order, fill_value=0)
```

Or, using a [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html):

```
df_confusion = pd.crosstab(pd.Categorical(orig, categories=order, ordered=True),
                           pd.Categorical(pred, categories=order, ordered=True))
```

Comment: Thank you! df_confusion.reindex(columns=order) worked for me! And the necessary column and row names can be extracted using list(self.df_confusion.index) and list(self.df_confusion.columns). I even tried using .reindex, I don't know how I managed to fumble this.